# Boolean mask used to separate data, but when plotting, matplotlib returns: 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous....'

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

This is a small snippet of my original large (7000+ row) dataframe, indexed by date, with columns for flood size (Size) and precipitation (ppt):

```
                Size    ppt
date
2017-09-11      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-12      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-13      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-14      1.0     34.709998
2017-09-15      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-16      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-17      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-18      0.0     0.600000
2017-09-19      3.0     157.439998
```

I have used the code below to split it into groups that I want to compare, which are 'Rainfall on flood days (when Size=1,2 or 3, ppt>=0)', 'Rainfall on days with no floods (Size=0, ppt>0), and then removing the days where no rain or floods happened (Size=0, ppt=0).

```
#initial separation of data

mask = df1['Size'].eq(0)
dfFl = df1[~mask] #Days with floods
dfnFl = df1[mask] #Days without floods i.e Size=0

# remove days with no rain or flood.

mask = df1['ppt3'].eq(0)
dfnFl = df1[~mask] #Days with rain but no flood
dfnil = df1[mask] #Days with no flood or rain
```

Using this snippet of my dataframe, this process returns:

```
#dfFl (days with flood):
                Size    ppt
date
2017-09-14      1.0     34.709998
2017-09-19      3.0     157.439998

#dfnFl (days with rainfall but no flood):
                Size    ppt
date
2017-09-18      0.0     0.600000

#dfnil (days with no rain nor flood):
                Size    ppt
date
2017-09-11      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-12      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-13      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-15      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-16      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-17      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-18      0.0     0.600000
```

I want to compare these groups (dfFl and dfnFl) by viewing them in a simple box plot:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
axs[0, 0].boxplot(dfFl['ppt'], dfnFl['ppt'])
plt.show()
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-2b9c443a4940> in <module>()
      2
      3 fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
----> 4 axs[0, 0].boxplot(dfFl['ppt'], dfnFl['ppt'])
      5 plt.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, 
*args, **kwargs)
   1708                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1709                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1710             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1711         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1712         if pre_doc is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in 
boxplot(self, x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, 
bootstrap, usermedians, conf_intervals, meanline, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, 
showfliers, boxprops, labels, flierprops, medianprops, meanprops, capprops, 
whiskerprops, manage_xticks, autorange, zorder)
   3443                            meanline=meanline, showfliers=showfliers,
   3444                            capprops=capprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops,
-> 3445                            manage_xticks=manage_xticks, zorder=zorder)
   3446         return artists
   3447 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in bxp(self, 
bxpstats, positions, widths, vert, patch_artist, shownotches, showmeans, 
showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, whiskerprops, flierprops, medianprops, 
capprops, meanprops, meanline, manage_xticks, zorder)
   3773 
   3774             # notched boxes
-> 3775             if shownotches:
   3776                 box_x = [box_left, box_right, box_right, cap_right, 
box_right,
   3777                          box_right, box_left, box_left, cap_left, 
box_left,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
__nonzero__(self)
    953         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    954                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all()."
--> 955                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    956 
    957     __bool__ = __nonzero__
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't really understand what is going wrong here, as when I view the filtered dataframes, they look normal (as shown above). Any ideas out there?

Thanks

Comment: Your examples only show ``pandas`` (I guess), there is no ``matplotlib`` involved; You also need to show more of the backtrace: this error can be produced by so many things...

Comment: Sorry, I have now included the relevant matplotlib part of my code and the full erro details

Answer (score 0):

boxplot expects a single argument `x` (`axs[0, 0].boxplot(x)`). However you provide two arguments. This will of course fail, because the second argument is interpreted to qualify if notches are to be shown and should hence take either `True` or `False`.

It looks like you want to plot two boxplots instead,

```
axs[0, 0].boxplot(dfFl['ppt'])
axs[0, 0].boxplot(dfnFl['ppt'])
```

Or

```
axs[0, 0].boxplot([dfFl['ppt'],dfnFl['ppt']])
```